# self join and ignore nulls on one table / side only

Tags: php, mysql, null, left-join, string

I have 2 tables.

One table defines customer connections:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cust_connections` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `short_name` char(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `source_fnn` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `dest_fnn` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `service_type` char(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `ladder_side` char(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    INSERT INTO `cust_connections` (`id`, `short_name`, `source_fnn`, `dest_fnn`, `service_type`, `ladder_side`) VALUES
    (1, 'cust1', 'N2843453A', '', 'HD_300_Connect', 'src only'),
    (2, 'cust2', '', 'N2843600A', 'HD_300_Connect', 'dest only'),
    (3, 'cust3', 'N2720257O', 'N2731164O', 'DVB25_188byte', 'both'),
    (4, 'cust4', 'N27xxx7O', 'N2731164O', 'DVB25_188byte', 'src ukn'),
    (5, 'cust4', 'N27xxx7O', '', 'DVB25_188byte', 'ukn +blk');

ALTER TABLE `cust_connections`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `cust_connections`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=18;
```

The other table defines the equipment:

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cust_port` (
    `id` smallint(11) NOT NULL,
      `system_name` char(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `slot_no` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `port_no` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `port_fnn` char(9) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    INSERT INTO `cust_port` (`id`, `system_name`, `slot_no`, `port_no`, `port_fnn`) VALUES
    (1, '01-06C2:source', '7', '1', 'N2843453A'),
    (2, '01-27B4:dest', '1', '2', 'N2843600A'),
    (3, '01-27B6:source+dst', '17', '3', 'N2720257O'),
    (4, '01-27B6:dst+src', '17', '3', 'N2731164O'),
    (5, '01-32C6:dup_fnn1', '1', '2', 'N2845070O'),
    (26, '01-32C6:dup_fnn2', '1', '3', 'N2845070O'),
    (27, '01-32D6:no_fnn', '1', '4', ''),
    (28, '01-32D6:diff_fnn', '1', '4', 'x123456');

ALTER TABLE `cust_port`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `cust_port`
MODIFY `id` smallint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=29;
```

SQl Result is:

```
 cc_id  short_name  source_fnn  dest_fnn    service_type    ladder_side     src_system_name     src_slot_no     src_port_no     src_port_fnn    dst_system_name     dst_slot_no     dst_port_no     dst_port_fnn    
1       cust1       N2843453A               HD_300_Connect  src only       01-06C2:source         7                  1          N2843453A       01-32D6:no_fnn       1              4   
2       cust2       N2843600A               HD_300_Connect  dest only      01-32D6:no_fnn         1                  4                          01-27B4:dest         1              2               N2843600A
3       cust3       N2720257O   N2731164O   DVB25_188byte   both           01-27B6:source+dst    17                  3          N2720257O       01-27B6:dst+src      17             3               N2731164O
4       cust4       N27xxx7O    N2731164O   DVB25_188byte   src ukn        NULL                   NULL               NULL       NULL            01-27B6:dst+src      17             3               N2731164O
5       cust4       N27xxx7O                DVB25_188byte   ukn +blk       NULL                   NULL               NULL       NULL            01-32D6:no_fnn       1              4
```

I am doing a join on the two tables.

The problem is, I want to exclude the row if the port_fnn is null, but display the row if any of the customer source or destination fnns are null.

I am doing a left (self) join to match on source and destination fnns against equipment fnn. Unfortunately my customer fnns must be able to have null values.

My query works great if there are no null values in the equipment table.
My query is:

```
SELECT 
cc.id AS cc_id, short_name,source_fnn, dest_fnn, service_type,ladder_side,
src.system_name AS src_system_name,
src.slot_no AS src_slot_no,
src.port_no AS src_port_no,
src.port_fnn AS src_port_fnn,
dst.system_name AS dst_system_name,
dst.slot_no AS dst_slot_no, 
dst.port_no AS dst_port_no,
dst.port_fnn AS dst_port_fnn
FROM cust_connections cc 
 LEFT JOIN cust_port src on cc.source_fnn=src.port_fnn 
 LEFT JOIN cust_port dst on cc.dest_fnn=dst.port_fnn
```

In my result set:
Row  1 - Has a source fnn only. I want the result to be empty for destination fields ie:

```
cc_id   short_name  source_fnn  dest_fnn    service_type    ladder_side     src_system_name     src_slot_no     src_port_no     src_port_fnn    dst_system_name     dst_slot_no     dst_port_no     dst_port_fnn    
1       cust1       N2843453A               HD_300_Connect  src only       01-06C2:source         7                  1          N2843453A       NULL                NULL             NULL            NULL
```

The query is detecting a null fnn and populating with the equipment that does not have an fnn associated. I.e.: 01-32D6:no_fnn.

The same issue occurs for source_system_name on row 2 and dst_system_name on row 5.

Comment: Do u want to exclude port_fnn from equipment table?

Comment: what would be your desired outcome with this example? and can you also keep the table names the same between query and data? its slightly confusing

Comment: @Nigel, i just looked at your desired outcome. it is identical to the results from your query except one thing, you have, in the last row, data from the row you said you didn't want any data from. aka `equip4               4/2` this is from the row you said you desired it not be displayed because it has a null port_fnn

Comment: @philipxy thats what i said in my comment, its also equip1 not equip4

Comment: Hi, Sorry I am having so much trouble explaining the problem.

The row "cust_port" row with 55555 works correctly with my query, because 5555 is not in any customer connection rows.

The row "cust_port" with "null" fnn is the only issue. I want this row to not produce any output if "cust_port.port_fnn" contains null.

Comment: @philipxy.
Thanks - I will update with actual data when I'm back at work tomorrow 
to make it as accurate as possible. My results were from memory and to try and minimise amount of data...

I know 55555 is working as I expected - ie. not included. 
Thank you for input though, I have found it difficult to formulate this question and your input has helped.

Comment: Thank you for giving us a way to see the output. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please declare any candidate keys (primary keys/unique not null), foreign keys and other constraints. (Eg your comment to my answer expresses some constraints.)

Comment: @philipxy. Sorry I don't understand what you mean by this. 
ither change port_fnn to be nullable and use NULL instead of '' - Please excuse my newbiness :)

Comment: Please show your (COMPLETE) expected output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'' (the empty string) is not NULL. (Which sqlfiddle outputs as "(null)".)

In text, do not write "NULL" or "<NULL>" or "null" or "(null)" to refer to the empty string as you did originally in your question. Be clear what is '' and what is NULL.

'' = '' but NULL <> NULL. So your LEFT JOIN finds a match between columns cc.source_fnn and src.port_fnn and between columns cc.dest_fnn and cust_port port_fnn when the equality tests involve ''. But you don't want the LEFT JOIN to match those rows.

You can say that by:

1. Declaring all _fnn columns nullable, ie as NULL (the default) instead of NOT NULL and using NULL in your tables where you now use '' (the empty string). Then your query will give the correct answer!
2. Requiring port_fnn <> '':

   ```
   FROM cust_connections cc
   LEFT JOIN cust_port src
   ON cc.source_fnn=src.port_fnn AND cc.source_fnn <> ''
   LEFT JOIN cust_port  dst
   ON cc.dest_fnn=dst.port_fnn AND cc.dest_fnn <> '';
   ```
3. Removing those rows from cust_port before you LEFT JOIN with it:

   ```
   FROM cust_connections cc
   LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT * FROM cust_port WHERE port_fnn <> ''
       ) src
   ON cc.source_fnn=src.port_fnn
   LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT * FROM cust_port WHERE port_fnn <> ''
       ) dst
   ON cc.dest_fnn=dst.port_fnn;
   ```

Sqlfiddle [for 1 using NULL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edb5c7/2) and [for 2 & 3 using ''](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50fe3/1). These have an added second cust_port row with absent port_fnn to show that the above give the correct result. Your query used with '' incorrectly generates other spurious rows from that.

If you want NULL from the LEFT JOIN shown as the empty string on output then you can use IFNULL for those columns:

IFNULL(dst.port_fnn,'') AS dst_port_fnn

Comment: Thank you so much - this works. I have gone with 2 and also adding IFNULL(dst.port_fnn,'') AS dst_port_fnn to cover both NULL and '' eventualities.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `where` clause like:

```
where  (cc.source_fnn is null or cc.dest_fnn is null)
       or (src.port_fnn is not null or dst.port_fnn is not null)
```

Now it will always display rows with an empty `source_fnn` or `dest_fnn`.  When both are filled, it will filter out rows where a matching `port_fnn` column is empty.

So you'll get rows with missing foreign keys, but suppress rows where the foreign key references a row with an empty column.  At least that's what I think you're looking for.  Please clarify your question if it's not.

Comment: Thanks - I tried this with same result.
Also tried with
`FROM cust_connections cc 
 LEFT JOIN cust_port src on cc.source_fnn=src.port_fnn and src.port_fnn is not null
 LEFT JOIN cust_port dst on cc.dest_fnn=dst.port_fnn and dst.port_fnn is not null`

Comment: @Nigel & Andomar For NULLs in input: It already does "always display rows with an empty source_fnn or dest_fnn" since they are on the left of a L JOIN & "filter out rows where a matching port_fnn column is empty" since they are on the right of a L JOIN & NULL can't match. Ie the query is correct. But Nigel's "null" meant *empty string*! If there are 0 or 1 empty port_fnns then we need all rows. Otherwise if source_fnn & dest_fnn act like foreign keys when non-empty then we can GROUP BY cc.id HAVING src.id <=> MIN(src.id) AND dst.id <=> MIN(dst.id). (Then we NULL columns per DRapp's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do can be done with an IF() for each respective source/destination column to MASK the name and ports.  Most of the time people will try to do something to PREVENT nulls and show something like an empty string... Instead, you want the reverse... if the "port_fnn" is null, you want to HIDE those elements.

So I have done an IF( expression, result if true, result if false ) for each column.  So, if the port_fnn IS NULL, then show null as the result, otherwise return whatever the column was (system name, slot, port, etc)

```
SELECT 
      cc.id AS cc_id, 
      short_name,
      source_fnn, 
      dest_fnn, 
      service_type,ladder_side,
      if( src.port_fnn = '', NULL, src.system_name ) AS src_system_name,
      if( src.port_fnn = '', NULL, src.slot_no ) AS src_slot_no,
      if( src.port_fnn = '', NULL, src.port_no ) AS src_port_no,
      if( src.port_fnn = '', NULL, src.port_fnn ) AS src_port_fnn,
      if( dst.port_fnn = '', NULL, dst.system_name ) AS dst_system_name,
      if( dst.port_fnn = '', NULL, dst.slot_no ) AS dst_slot_no, 
      if( dst.port_fnn = '', NULL, dst.port_no ) AS dst_port_no,
      if( dst.port_fnn = '', NULL, dst.port_fnn ) AS dst_port_fnn
   FROM 
      cust_connections cc 
          LEFT JOIN cust_port src 
             on cc.source_fnn = src.port_fnn
          LEFT JOIN cust_port dst 
             on cc.dest_fnn = dst.port_fnn
```

I adjusted the query above to work on your data... NULL is different than an empty string.  I copied your tables and sample data to SQL Fiddle and then the above query.  It appears to be showing NULLS for the source and destination respectively.

[SQLFiddle per your example structure and data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d30c3/1)

Comment: Hi, You are on the right track I think...
This query didn't work though, it is still showing equipment when customer equipment is null. Also slight typo in statement src.port_ffn should be src.port_fnn

Comment: @Nigel, revised and created SQLFiddle of your table/data results.

Comment: Your solution also worked, but I have gone with philipxy solution as it is a bit simpler to implement. Thank you so much for your input it is very much appreciated

Comment: @Nigel & DRapp: This does not work when the empty string is used for absent fnn. (Mine does.) Because it does not exclude cust_port rows with empty fnns from participating in the joins. You can see this by adding a second cust_port row with empty port_fnn. [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84fdd4/1). It works for NULL because then the original query works. Because the OUTER JOIN does not match those rows. So this answer just tells how to get empty strings for NULLs. Nigel: You should add such a row to your tests.

Comment: @Nigel & DRapp: SELECT DISTINCT gets rid of duplicate matches to multiple cust_port rows with empty port_fnn.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer was in the context of an earlier version of the qeustion where the example input unclearly described the empty string ie '' as being NULL/< NULL >/null so it seemed like the "" values were NULL. Had they been NULL this answer applied. [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31dd9/1)]

**Wrong "desired output"**

The equip4 1/2 in your "desired output" is a mistake, you want equip1 1/2 from port id 2 via 4444. After you correct that, the desired output is what you described (unclearly) elsewhere.

**NULL port_fnn is not a problem**

The null port_fnn is not putting anything into the table from the query. The LEFT JOINs never match it.

**What rows do you want?**

You are unclear. The only rows that you don't address are if a non-NULL source_fnn or dest_fnn has no matching port_fn. Then in the LEFT JOIN output it is paired with NULL port_fnn info.

It would be strange if you didn't want those rows. Not only would you have no row for a cust_connection but the other half of the extended information would be thrown away with it. Maybe you would only throw away rows where both source and dest are non-NULL with match. Still strange. You'd have to tell us whether you want these rows. Presumably you want them, beause they're in your query.

If every source_fnn and dest_fnn has a matching port_fnn, ie there are foreign keys from source_fnn adn dest_fnn to port_fnn, then this can never happen and your query is correct.

**So your query seems ok.**

And it seems that you wrongly guessed that it was failing for NULL port_fnn to explain why it differed from your wrong expected output.

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear. I have updated the question.
The customer_connections table can have 3 options.
Source FNN only. Destination FNN only or Both Source and Destination FNNs. These FNNs must match Equipment FNN's

Equipment FNN's can be an FNN or null. If the Equipment fnn is null. Equipment name should NOT appear in null entry's of customer_connection table. With current query, it does.
Kind regards
Nigel